# GetHue function in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hue

Im working on image-proccess application in windows phone. I need to use getHue function in it, and no getHue function their, what's the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should have a look at the [Nokia Imaging SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/imaging) and how to [work with Hue there](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/huesaturationfilter-class/huesaturationfilter-properties/hue-property.html).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Then one should overthink that I can't comment on his question and ask what he really wants to do with hue. For me this is the only answer for the question and more helpful than no answer at all ;)

Comment: well, you only need two approved edits to get over the 50rep hurdle that allows you to comment :_)